# Keyboard shortcut to switch between python console and the editor in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

In general, I'd like to know the keyboard shortcut for navigating to multiple sections like the project structure, editor, console. I'm using eclipse keymap configuration in pycharm. I used to switch between different views in eclipse using [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>]. But that is not working in pycharm.

I also used to use <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring the focus back to the editor when the focus is on any other view. That is also not working in pycharm.

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: Attention: Answer with most up-Votes is below accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is not what I needed when I came across this post. You can bind a hotkey to Python's console and go back to editor via F12. (See my answer below). `Bind "Python Console" (preference -> Keymap -> MainMenue.Tools "Python Console" to a keyboard shortcut. (e.g Alt-P). Then navigate to console via shortcut and back to editor via ESC.`

Comment: you should accept the actual answer to the question.

Comment: For anyones value, I mapped the Terminal window on my Mac to `Cmd`+`1` and the Python Console window to `Cmd`+`2`.  You can't toggle straight between the windows - these commands activate and deactivate the windows - but I find them helpful.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Pycharm 4, you can specify shortcuts with

**File / Settings / Appearance and Behaviour / Keymap**

You can create any shortcut you like, and bind it to the command "Python Console" (search for Console), which has no default keymapping.  Be aware that it is possible to have multiple consoles open at the same time (for example if you open one in the debugging window) so this may not always behave as you expect it to.

You can toggle back to the last editor window by hitting escape.

Comment: "You can toggle back to the last editor window by hitting escape" - very useful thanks, this isn't obvious!

Comment: This is the correct answer to the titled post "Keyboard shortcut to switch between python console and the editor in pycharm".

Comment: This is the correct answer, Change View doesn't help you in navigating to Python Console.

Comment: You can also toggle back to editor by pressing the same Python Console key you assigned.

Comment: Somehow a newly assigned shortcut does get the "Python console" focused, but Pycharm does not allow me to type directly. Toggling the "show variables" window fixed the issue.

Comment: @Bob I see this too, and think it's a bug. Closing the console and starting anew helps.

Answer (score 38):

If you mean the "Run" window (which has a console in it) you can open it/switch to it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>. See the screenshot for the two locations this is indicated.

As mentioned by vape, <kbd>Esc</kbd> should return you to your most recently used editor. Alternatively, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> again seems to return me to the first editor.

[image: Locations of shortcuts (View Menu and dock bar)]

Comment: This is useful in general, but unfortunately doesn't help when trying to navigate between editor window and the python console (title for this post by OP).  The python console is listed in View -> Tool Windows but has no keyboard shortcut assigned. Am checking whether a custom keyboard shortcut can be assigned to make this work.

Comment: Yes, can be done following the instructions provided in answer by @jafelds  It is not required to bring up the View -> Tool Windows pane, you can just use whatever you map as the keyboard shortcut to Python Console, and use escape to return to Editor window

Comment: @arcseldon  This *is* the correct answer. The `python console` is a flavor of `run` and `alt [/opt]-4` performs the correct navigation

Comment: @javadba - to be honest, i cannot even remember leaving those comments 16 months ago :)  Thanks for taking the time to reply - incidentally, which version of pycharm are you referring to? Been using webtstorm and intellij for the past year only - there's definitely been lots of updates and bug fixes in the interim.

Comment: Using intellij not pycharm as well. I just wanted to affirm this answer as being correct: since there are many alternates flying around.

Answer (score 28):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> pops up the Switcher dialog. You can then either use repeated <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to the window you want, or hit the corresponding number.

Answer (score 14):

To switch from Editor to Console: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
To switch from Console to Editor: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>

This works for me on **Ubuntu 16.04**

Answer (score 8):

Based on the title of the question the answer seem to be simply: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

This is true both for Eclipse bindings and the default.

It moves from the editor to the console/terminal and back when pressing it again. The only downside I see is that the terminal closes when moving back to the editor, I would like to keep it open and only move the focus.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Closure of the console window is not necessarily a downside, it leaves you more space with the editor.

Comment: `alt-4`  avoids the downside - it does exactly what is needed w/o side effects

Comment: this switches to the "Terminal" instead of the Python Console for me

Comment: Wrong. Console != Terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Summarizing the answers I found:

Best:
- Bind "Python Console" (preference -> Keymap -> MainMenue.Tools "Python Console" to a keyboard shortcut. (e.g Alt-P). Then navigate to console via shortcut and back to editor via ESC.

Alternatives:
- Ctrl+shift+tab opens a menu to navigate to alternative Views, pressing "P" navigates to python console. ESC brings you back.
- Manually Clicking on python console and pressing ESC brings you back to editor. Alt+F12 navigates you to "previous" view.

Answer (score 6):

Open `Preferences` and then select `Tools` -> `Terminal`. Remove the check box from `Override IDE shortcuts`, and then you'll be able to focus the Terminal tool window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F12</kbd> on Mac and hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> will put you back in the editor that you were last in.

This might cause issues if you're trying to run a program in the terminal which needs to receive the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key in order to function correctly.

[image: PyCharm - Preferences - Tools - Terminal]

Comment: This is what I was looking for many years. `Alt + F12` and then `esc` worked to switch back and forth after the terminal override change.

Comment: This works for the terminal, not for the "Python console" as asked.

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> to switch between editor and the recently used window. That is what I usually do quickly because I have python console as the recently used window.

Answer (score 6):

### Updated answer for PyCharm 2020:

After trying them none of the previous answers seem to still apply so here is how to do it in PyCharm 2020.

To get into the python console where you can *actually type commands* (not just select the window) you have to rebind "**Python or Debug Console**" under Tools in the Keymap section of the settings (open with ctrl+alt+s)

Getting back to the editor is Escape by default but can be changed by rebinding "**Focus Editor**" under the Editor Actions folder.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on PyCharm 2018.3.2 Community Edition using Win7 and I am able to switch to the code editor by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and to the Python Console but pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>⌃⇥</kbd> and navigate between files opened in the editor, and tool windows. This is called the **Switcher**.

[image]

Reference:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-between-files-and-tool-windows.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigation-between-ide-components.html

Answer (score 2):

I think ctrl+tab to switch should be enough for most of user but a more time-efficient way is also wanted to some extent.

[Go to here and set your keyboard shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edhKf.png)

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> then release only <kbd>TAB</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> to open Python Console directly. This method is similar to other answers, but let you to avoid walking through other options.

And then  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close this console.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the keyboard shortcuts you are looking for are:
Ctrl+0 = select shell
Ctrl+9 = select editor
These are default keyboard shortcuts for python.

Answer (score 0):

Bind "Python Console" (preference -> Keymap -> MainMenue.Tools "Python Console" to a keyboard shortcut. (e.g Alt-P). Then navigate to console via shortcut and back to editor via ESC

As you yourself said this is the best answer to switch to the "Python Console", not to the "Terminal", not to the Run window.

You may consider selecting this as the best answer...