# What is the keyboard shortcut for getting into Variables section in Debug Window in PyCharm

Tags: debugging, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

I try to avoid usage of mouse. When the process is stopped in debugging, I am in Debugger window. Specifically in section called "Frames" which displays current stacktrace. How can I navigate to section called "Variables" with a keyboard only?

Answer (score 0):

I guess ALT+5 will help you ;
https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/pycharm-win/cheatsheet

- [Keyboard shortcut to switch between python console and the editor in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971221/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-python-console-and-the-editor-in-pycharm)